# Each .ref listener counts simultaneously connection to firebase realtime database?

Tags: firebase-realtime-database

I have a doubt with the term “simultaneously connection” on firebase realtime database.

If in the same page.html I have three listeners like this

```
var ref1 = db.ref("path1");
var ref2= db.ref("path2");
var ref3 = db.ref("path3");
```

Each reference listener counts a one simultaneously connection to database? 3 simultaneously connection in a unique client/page.html?

On the other hand, what would be the best practice to close the connection on a page? In wich moment i have to close the connection on the life cycle of the page?

Comment: There is a single client created for each client app (or browser tab), not for each `DatabaseReference`. So the code you shared would open a single connection.

Comment: Then a single simultaneous connection to database is opened by ‘firebase.initializeApp(config);’ instead by databasereference listener no?.

Comment: Initializing firebaseApp doesn't necessarily mean you're using the database. The connection is opened the first time you attach a listener or write to the database.

Comment: But if open multiple database reference listeners on the same page are multiple simultaneous connections?

Comment: No, that is a single connection. There is a single client created for each client app (or browser tab).

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen So, if I load a user top list with multiple calls to get data for each entry, it's still only counted as one connection? I'm asking since I try to optimize my database. I can have more data in each node or make more calls to get data from various nodes. More calls would be preferable but not if I hit the limits of course. Very grateful for a reply! :)

Comment: A single client will usually make a single connection. If you see something else, post a new question with the minimal standalone code that we can run to reproduce that behavior.